# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the laye

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten

model=Sequential()`model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model.add(Dense(units=128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=6,activation="softmax")) 
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])


def main():
file_uploaded = st.file_uploader("Choose File", type=["png","jpg","jpeg"])
class_btn = st.button("Classify")
if file_uploaded is not None:    
    image = Image.open(file_uploaded)
    st.image(image, caption='Uploaded Image', use_column_width=True)    
if class_btn:
    if file_uploaded is None:
        st.write("Invalid command, please upload an image")
    else:
        with st.spinner('Model working....'):
            plt.imshow(image)
            plt.axis("off")
            predictions = predict(image)
            time.sleep(1)
            st.success('Classified')
            st.write(predictions)
            st.pyplot(fig)

def predict(image):
classifier_model = "C:/Users/houcem/Desktop/Doctor Sina/code/ECG1.h5"
IMAGE_SHAPE = (64,64,3)
model = load_model(classifier_model, compile=False)
test_image = image.resize((64,64))
test_image = preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image)

test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
preds = np.argmax(model.predict(test_image),axis=-1)
index = ['Fusion Beat','Normal Beat','Unknown Beat','Supraventricular ectopic Beat','Ventricular ectopic beat']
print("------------------------------------\n")
print("\nprediction -> ",index[preds[0]])
print("\n-------------------------------------")
                   

text = "The predicted type is " + str(index[preds[0]]) 
return text
```

i got this error any help please

ValueError( ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 64, 64, 4]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the full reproducible example (imports for example)...